# CNN Prediction output to masked image

Tags: computer-vision, conv-neural-network, image-segmentation, semantic-segmentation

Given an output prediction of shape [1,21,388,88] from my Unet. How can I plot it as a masked image? I am using PASCAL dataset.

Thanks!

Comment: The active router link will have a class applied to it.  You could use that and hide/show images based on the parent's class

Comment: Put an img tag in for both the active and inactive images, give them class names.  hide the active img by default with `display: none;` show it when the parent has the class `router-link-exact-active`.  do the opposite for the inactive images.  does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

```
Basically you can do something like this and give conditional so when they meet requirements you get the style/ image you want

   
 <template>
      <menu>
        <router-link to="/">
          <li>
            <div :class="toggleData ? 'style-one' : 'style-two'"> <!-- Check if toggledata true we use style-one css, if not style-two -->
              <img :src="toggleData ? 'image-one-link' : 'image-link-two'" /> <!-- Check if toggledata true we use image-one-link, if not image-two-link -->
            </div>
            <div class="name" >Home</div>
          </li>
        </router-link>
        <router-link to="/distination2">
          <li>
            <div class="Pic">
              <img src='' />
            </div>
            <div class="Name">Home2</div>
          </li>
        </router-link>
        <router-link to="/distination3">
          <li>
            <div class="Pic">
              <img src='' />
            </div>
            <div class="Name">Home3</div>
          </li>
        </router-link>
        <button @click="buttonClick"> Click Me </button> <!-- When button click we change toggleData value to true -->
      </menu>
    </template>
    
    <script>
    export default {
      data() {
        return {
          toggleData: false,
        };
      },
      methods: {
        buttonClick() {
          this.toggleData = true;
        },
      },
    }
    </script>
    
    <style scoped>
    .style-one {
      background: red;
    }
    .style-two {
      background: blue;
    }
    </style>
```

Comment: This does work since I have already tried something like that. However, I have different picture for each routerlink and each one of them have one a pic-active and pic-inactive image. I need then to write a new method for each and every one of them since I cannot use toggledata for every div (if it is true it will be true for all and all will change picture at the same time which is not what I want to achieve). Thank you for your awnser anyway :)

Comment: Have you try it using a conditional statement with $route.fullPath? so when it meets the exact routerlink we will change the image link. You could put it under 'computed' in Vue.js